# C# lock file XML for threads

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, locking

I have a doubt about lock statment

All examples that i see, lock statment is used for global variable in a same form, but in my case that no happend, then i don't know how avoid the error "file is used for another..."

My case.
User go to form1, and in the form1, add lines to XML. While, in second plane, a thread take that XML and send info to server and update state objects in this XML.
Then when user and thread write at the same (one by user and other by second plane, the xml save throw error)
I'm doing that

```
form1
{
  var A = takeAllABCObjects();
  var A = A + new objects();
  saveABCObjects(A);
}

Thread in second plane in all time life of app
{
  var B = takeAllABCObjects();
  B = UpdateObjectsB();
  saveABCObjects(B);
}


Class saveABCObjects(list<objects> ABCObjects)
{
 lock (ABCObjects)
 {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<objects>));
     TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("ABC.xml");
     serializer.Serialize(textWriter, ABCObjects);
     textWriter.Close();
 }
}
```

Then my question is...
lock statment use are wrong?
how should i use it?

Tnx and sorry for my eng

Comment: The error message is telling you that a file is in use. I.e. it's file handle is open. This is unrelated to the c# `lock` statement, that only provides for a protection of a critical section of code, but has no relevance to open file handles.

Comment: You should probably be using a Semaphore or Mutex instead of a lock https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also, if the purpose was to use the lock to prevent multiple writes to the same file (whether that's a good idea notwithstanding), you are probably locking on a different list each time so it's doing nothing of use.

Comment: @CharlesMager for protection of concurrent file access, given the error message the OP received, the OS is already doing a fine job. Although opening it as not shared would be an improvement.

Comment: all examples that i find for mutex and semaphore, work in the same "form". Can u do a example for my case with that?

Edit. In my case would be something like that??

Class saveABCObjects(list<objects> ABCObjects)
{
 if (mutex.WaitOne (1000))
 {
     write statments....

     mutex.ReleaseMutex();
 }
}

Comment: Side note: locking on public objects is discouraged (so to some extend your `lock` statement is wrong). It has nothing to do with file level locking you are seeing. "File locked by another..." is very common problem so please make sure to search for existing answers (also 99% of them would be "you are not closing the file somewhere" which likely the problem in your case too).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov then u recommend that i check if file is in use and do a loop wainting while are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a `wrapper` class to access your XML

Sonce your two threads do not know when each other is accessing the file let a class do it on it's own.

I was thinking of something like this :

```
public class SynchronizedXMLAccess : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Mutex _access = new Mutex();
    public FileStream Fs { get; private set; }

    public SynchronizedXMLAccess(String path, FileMode mode = FileMode.Open, FileAccess access = FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare sharing = FileShare.None)
    {
        _access.WaitOne();
        Fs = File.Open(path, mode, access, sharing);
    }


    #region Implementation of IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Fs.Close();
        _access.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

You'll need to instantiate the class to access a file, but it will ensure it is only opened once between the threads. And since it implements `IDisposable` you'll be able to instantiate it with a `using` statement

It's the most basic form, so if you use it, you won't be able to access 2 different files, only one file wll be able to be opened across the threads

**EDIT :**

Usage example :

```
Class saveABCObjects(list<objects> ABCObjects)
{
  using(var sync = new SynchronizedXMLAccess(...)) 
  {
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<objects>));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(sync.Fs);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, ABCObjects);
    textWriter.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: The bonus point is that if a thread want to access a file it will not raise an exception but instead make the thread wait.

Comment: in this case the call would be:
SynchronizedXMLAccess.SynchronizedXMLAccess(...);
saveABCObjects(List<objects>);
SynchronizedXMLAccess.Dispose();
right? and when both threads call the function, one will wait for the other dispose right?

Comment: ^_^, tnx. And when two threads call saveABCObjects(), one of them will wait in "using" until the other ended, right?

Comment: That's the whole idea :)

Comment: You might want to add a timeout in the `_access.WaitOne();` call, so that if the other thread is locked or didn't release the mutex, you won't be blocked here foreve

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your thread and form are not using the same lock object.  I don't know how you are creating your thread but I've written up a little console app with 2 tasks that will lock and alternately write and read to a file.  You have to pass in the same lock object to each task in order for this to work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lockObject = new object();
    var fileName = @"C:\Users\kevin\Documents\test.txt";
    Action<object> action1 = (o) =>
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (i++ < 1000)
        {
            // do stuff that doesn't require the lock
            lock (o)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In Thread1");
                // do stuff that does require the lock
                var text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, "\tThread1");
            }
        }
    };
    // Pass in our shared lock object
    Task task1 = new Task(action1, lockObject);
    task1.Start();
    Action<object> action2 = (o) =>
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (i++ < 1000)
        {
            // do stuff that doesn't require the lock
            lock (o)
            {
                // do stuff that does require the lock
                Console.WriteLine("In Thread2");
                var text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, "\tThread2");
            }
        }
    };
    // Pass in our shared lock object
    Task task2 = new Task(action2, lockObject);
    task2.Start();

    // sleep main thread and let the 2 threads do their stuff
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open the file with write permissions and "read" Sharing rights you should be fine

so processA opens for writeing

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Open("file.ext",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.Read))
```

and processB opens for reading

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Open("file.ext",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

adds a bit of code but it should allow one process to write while another is reading

as for the reader not going past the end is a whole other story

Comment: But the processB too write. first "read" all object, next update the state of them, and next "write" and overwrite the XML :/